# what are the ways in which I can ensure the browser fetches the updated file from cloudfront

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, versioning, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup static files (css, images and js) files on a cloudfront distribution and am using the cloudfront URLs of the files to refer to them in the JSP files.
I have setup cache-control value to a max of one month.

Suppose if I modify the css/js files before cache expires and update the files in the cloudfront distribution after invalidating the original object.

What are the ways in which I can make sure that the browser fetches the updated file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon recommends a technique they call "versioning" which basically means change the object's filename when you change the object.

The CloudFront developer manual ( http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?ReplacingObjects.html ) describes it as follows:

> We recommend that you use the common
>   technique of versioning to give
>   yourself better control of your
>   content. Versioning means that you
>   assign each object in the origin
>   server a version number. For example,
>   instead of calling the file image.jpg,
>   you call it image_1.jpg. Then when you
>   want to start serving a new version of
>   the file, you name that new file
>   image_2.jpg, and you update your links
>   to point to image_2.jpg. With
>   versioning, you do not have to wait
>   for an object to expire before you can
>   serve a new version of it.
>
> Even though you might be versioning
>   your objects, we still recommend you
>   set an expiration date that you feel
>   is appropriate for your objects. For
>   more information see Object
>   Expiration.